# How can you select rows based on a character string when you only want to reference part of that string in r?

Tags: r, select

I have a dataset with an ID column that's 8-10 characters long. Each ID contains information on a subject's family, their position in that family (if they're a parent, a proband, or a sibling), and their location. Here's a clip of the ID column:

```
temp <- as.data.table(new("character", .Data = c("45-D11150341", "45-D11180321", 
                                                 "45-D11220022", "45-D11240432", "45-D11270422", "45-D11290422", 
                                                 "45-D11320321", "45-D11500021", "45-D11500311", "45-D11520011", 
                                                 "H0050022S", "H0050432S", "H0060331S", "H0180422S", "H0200021S", 
                                                 "H0200432S", "H0210011S", "H0210422S", "H0250021S", "H0250311S"), 
            value.labels = NULL, value.filter = NULL))
colnames(temp) <- "nidaid"

> temp
          nidaid
 1: 45-D11150341
 2: 45-D11180321
 3: 45-D11220022
 4: 45-D11240432
 5: 45-D11270422
 6: 45-D11290422
 7: 45-D11320321
 8: 45-D11500021
 9: 45-D11500311
10: 45-D11520011
11:    H0050022S
12:    H0050432S
13:    H0060331S
14:    H0180422S
15:    H0200021S
16:    H0200432S
17:    H0210011S
18:    H0210422S
19:    H0250021S
20:    H0250311S
```

I need to create a column that indicates whether or not a subject is a proband and not a parent or sibling. A proband is indicated by a "00" in a specific place. That information in the patients that are apart of the "45-D" group comes after the first 4 numbers (eg, 45-Dxxxx00xx) in the 5th and 6th spot. In the "H" group, that number comes after the first 3 numbers (eg, Hxxx00xxS) in the 4th and 5th slot. If those spots are anything but "00" then they're not a proband.

The column I want to create should have a 1 indicating proband or a 2 indicating not a proband. It should look like:

```
> temp
          nidaid goal
 1: 45-D11150341    2
 2: 45-D11180321    2
 3: 45-D11220022    1
 4: 45-D11240432    2
 5: 45-D11270422    2
 6: 45-D11290422    2
 7: 45-D11320321    2
 8: 45-D11500021    1
 9: 45-D11500311    2
10: 45-D11520011    1
11:    H0050022S    1
12:    H0050432S    2
13:    H0060331S    2
14:    H0180422S    2
15:    H0200021S    1
16:    H0200432S    2
17:    H0210011S    1
18:    H0210422S    2
19:    H0250021S    1
20:    H0250311S    2
```

I've used the following code to do this but it thinks a consecutive "00" anywhere is what I'm looking for.

```
temp2 <- temp %>% 
  mutate(pro.sib = fifelse(grepl("00", nidaid) == TRUE, 1, 2))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) option using [stringr](/questions/tagged/stringr) and [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

temp <- as.data.table(new("character", .Data = c("45-D11150341", "45-D11180321", 
                                                 "45-D11220022", "45-D11240432", "45-D11270422", "45-D11290422", 
                                                 "45-D11320321", "45-D11500021", "45-D11500311", "45-D11520011", 
                                                 "H0050022S", "H0050432S", "H0060331S", "H0180422S", "H0200021S", 
                                                 "H0200432S", "H0210011S", "H0210422S", "H0250021S", "H0250311S"), 
                          value.labels = NULL, value.filter = NULL))
colnames(temp) <- "nidaid"

temp %>% 
  mutate(goal = case_when(str_detect(nidaid, pattern = "^45.*00.{2}$") == T ~ 1,
                          str_detect(nidaid, pattern = "^H.*00.{3}$") == T ~ 1,
                          TRUE ~ 2))

#>          nidaid goal
#> 1  45-D11150341    2
#> 2  45-D11180321    2
#> 3  45-D11220022    1
#> 4  45-D11240432    2
#> 5  45-D11270422    2
#> 6  45-D11290422    2
#> 7  45-D11320321    2
#> 8  45-D11500021    1
#> 9  45-D11500311    2
#> 10 45-D11520011    1
#> 11    H0050022S    1
#> 12    H0050432S    2
#> 13    H0060331S    2
#> 14    H0180422S    2
#> 15    H0200021S    1
#> 16    H0200432S    2
#> 17    H0210011S    1
#> 18    H0210422S    2
#> 19    H0250021S    1
#> 20    H0250311S    2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works. Would mind explaining the pattern you used? Is it a regular expression or a backreference?

Comment: Sure, @garsimpitoyable! This is [tag:regex]. My logical reasoning was a string started with (^) H or 45 that has zero or more (*) characters except a new line (.) that has 00 and it is ended ($) by exactly 2 ({.2}) or 3 ({.3}) characters except a new line (.). If you are interested in more details, you could check the second page of [`stringr` cheat sheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/strings.pdf) where `regex` syntax it is explained in more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the positions you could use `substr`:

```r
library(data.table)
temp <- as.data.table(new("character", .Data = c("45-D11150341", "45-D11180321", 
    "45-D11220022", "45-D11240432", "45-D11270422", "45-D11290422", 
    "45-D11320321", "45-D11500021", "45-D11500311", "45-D11520011", 
    "H0050022S", "H0050432S", "H0060331S", "H0180422S", "H0200021S", 
    "H0200432S", "H0210011S", "H0210422S", "H0250021S", "H0250311S"), 
    value.labels = NULL, value.filter = NULL))
colnames(temp) <- "nidaid"

temp[, goal := ifelse(substr(temp$nidaid,1,4)=="45-D", 
    ifelse(substr(temp$nidaid,9,10)=="00", 1,2),
    ifelse(substr(temp$nidaid,5,6)=="00", 1,2))]
temp
#>           nidaid goal
#>  1: 45-D11150341    2
#>  2: 45-D11180321    2
#>  3: 45-D11220022    1
#>  4: 45-D11240432    2
#>  5: 45-D11270422    2
#>  6: 45-D11290422    2
#>  7: 45-D11320321    2
#>  8: 45-D11500021    1
#>  9: 45-D11500311    2
#> 10: 45-D11520011    1
#> 11:    H0050022S    1
#> 12:    H0050432S    2
#> 13:    H0060331S    2
#> 14:    H0180422S    2
#> 15:    H0200021S    1
#> 16:    H0200432S    2
#> 17:    H0210011S    1
#> 18:    H0210422S    2
#> 19:    H0250021S    1
#> 20:    H0250311S    2
```